# SQL - query returning rows that presumably do not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
I run this query:

```
select * from tblbill
```

^Returns four rows. Particularly 4 distinct values of my field of interest `paymentduedate`^

I run a second query:

```
select b.paymentduedate, ledgertypeid, l.Billid
from tblbill as b
    join tblledger as l on b.billid = l.billid
```

^^Returns twenty rows with values of`b.paymentduedate` that are not returned when I run the `elect *`. `paymentduedate` is not a column in `tblledger`.

How is this possible? My first guess is that somehow rows in `tblBill` may be hidden but I do now know how to check that.

Comment: Something else is wrong - either the data is changing or it's somehow a different `tblBill`

Comment: Your records form the first table will duplicate for each match in the table you are joining.

Comment: you have 5 related records in tblledger for each record in tblbill thus having 4 records in tblbill makes it 20 records i guess? I hope by the way you could show actual records of this table and this would really helps a lot.

Comment: Instinct tells me you have a `one to many join`. I.E. You are showing every `tblbill` but also everytime it matches a record in `tblledger` based on your join.

Comment: `paymentduedate` is a calculated field? Can you post the DDL of `tblbill`?

Comment: @DStanley that's what it was. I needed to specify the correct database for tblbill. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be few reasons:

- There are 20 records with matching `billid` in table `tblledger` (the so called duplicate records came from the same 4 records in tblbill, you should count distinct values to determine if there are duplicates)
- after you ran the first query, that data was changed.

**Any way there is no such thing as hidden records**

Answer (score -3):

when you join you get all options. use inner, left or right join

Comment: This is not true. Just using `JOIN` is the same as `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Like I said, paymentduedate is a field unique to the tblbill so manipulating the type of join has no effect on the query results...